# Closing Main UWP app also closes all other hosted app views

Tags: c#, uwp

I just encountered a weird behavior in UWP apps when using the Protocol for Results activation.

1. First, activate the app using Protocol for Results activation from another app.
2. Open the app activated by Protocol for Results by its primary tile. You should now have the main app and the hosted app view running.
3. Close the main app.
4. The hosted app view is also closed without any error.

This also happens when you have the app already running and launch another view using the Protocol for Results activation. Closing the main app will also close the hosted app view.

Am I missing some configuration here? I haven't found this behavior stated in the docs too.

Please note that this is vanilla UWP. Not full trust and not WinUI. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Closing Main UWP app also closes all other hosted app views

I have to say it is **by design**, the launched view will host in main app, and  you can't interact with current app if the host view does not close. You can just close the view manually or call [`ReportCompleted`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.datatransfer.sharetarget.shareoperation.reportcompleted?view=winrt-22000) in host view.

If you force off the main app with Task Manage, the view will lost host and then close. Currently, there is no such configuration could disable this, if you do want such feature, I'd suggest you submit a feedback/feature request about this API/feature in the Feedback Hub. You could find the Feedback Hub in the Start Menu. Please select **Developer Platform**->**API Feedback** as the category when you submit your request. The related team will check the request.

**Update**

It's not good practice to open the `ProtocolApp` after launched result  view. Even though the result view is hosted in Main view, but it is  still sub-process of `ProtocolApp` that runs in the background, you could check task manager to verify this. The main process of `ProtocolApp` will resume from background, when we open `ProtocolApp` through its primary tile. And if we close the main process, the sub-process will be killed also. It's by design.

[image]

Comment: I can interact with both views (the main and the launched view) because the view is launched by another app. The problem is when the main app is closed (not the app that launched the view), the views that other apps has launched is also closed.

Comment: Could you explain `because the view is launched by another app`? Do you have at least  three apps?

Comment: Only 2 is needed. Let's call the app that can be activated with Protocol for Results as ProtocolApp. And the app that calls that app as ConsumerApp. When ConsumerApp launches ProtocolApp with a protocol for results activation and the user launches ProtocolApp through its primary tile, we now have 2 views of ProtocolApp (one for the main view of ProtocolApp, and one for the view launched by ConsumerApp). If the user closes the main view of ProtocolApp, the view launched by ConsumerApp is also closed without any error shown when debugging.

Comment: I have updated the case, please check that,

Comment: I understand. I hope this can be documented somewhere. Since I was stumped with this behavior for hours before realizing what is happening. It also happens when using other hosted views like game bar integration.